# Learning Javascript coming from Ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby

Ruby Hashes work differently than Javascript. I want to know how this Ruby syntax can be converted to Javascript as I am having trouble figuring it out.

```
number_of_hoverboards = "1"
puts "There are at least #{number_of_hoverboards}  hoverboard(s) in 
2015."
number_of_hoverboards = number_of_hoverboards.to_i
number_of_hoverboards -= 1

puts "There are at least #{number_of_hoverboards}  hoverboard(s) in 
2015."
```

Comment: There are no Ruby hashes in this code. What do you mean by "Ruby Hashes"?

Comment: @m.simonborg I think he means Ruby String interpolation, which starts with a hash symbol (`#{...}`). But yeah, very confusing, given that `Hash` has a very specific, different meaning in Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

What you're talking about are interpolated strings (`"we have #{number_of_dogs} dogs"`). Hashes (hash maps) are the dictionary structure in Ruby, written `{ breed: "pug", name: "Air Bun" }`, similar to JavaScript's object literals.

JavaScript has string interpolation written like this:

```
let numberOfDogs = 5;
let str = `We have ${numberOfDogs} dogs.`;
```

Comment: Yes, string interpolation is exclusive to strings marked with backticks.